# Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::attach does not exist error in laravel 8

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I was trying to add categories to products. I want to do it with a couple table between items and categories. I made a function in my controller to send it to the database. However, when I want to send it, I get the following error, and I don't know I can fix it. Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::attach does not exist.

Controller:

```
public function store(ItemsValidatorRequest $request)
    {
        if ($files = $request->image) {
            $destinationPath = 'images';
            $profileImage = date('YmdHis') . "." . $files->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $files->move($destinationPath, $profileImage);
        }
        else {
            return redirect()->back()->with('warning', 'Mislukt');
        }
        $user = Auth::user()->id;

        Item::create([
            'user_id' => $user,
            'item_title' => $request->titel,
            'item_img' => $profileImage,
            'item_description' => $request->beschrijving,
            'item_price' => $request->prijs,
            'item_slug' => $this->slugify($request->titel)
        ]);

        $items = Item::latest()->get();
   

     // line where it goes wrong
        $items->each->categories()->attach($request->categories);

        return redirect()
            ->route('admin.items.index')
            ->with('success', 'Het item is toegevoegd aan je verlanglijst');
    }
```

My model :

```
public function categories()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Category');
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Laravels` higher order function calls, take a single method call, not multiple. Therefor if you create an helper method on the `Item` class, it will solve your problem.

```
class Item {
    public function attachCategories($categories) {
        $this->categories()->attach($categories);
    }
}
```

Which will make it possible to assign categories like so.

```
$items->each->attachCategories($request->categories);
```